# What is correct update when the some indexes are not available?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference-methods

To update the Q table Q-learning takes the arg max of the Q values - the state, value mappings.

For example, in tic tac toe the state `XOX OXO -X-` contains two available positions, each marked by the `-` character. In order to evaluate the arg max should `temporal difference` calculate the arg max of just the available positions?

For the state `XOX OXO -X-` the arg max should be taken at index 6 and 8 ? (assuming zero indexing) If not then how should the arg max indexes be updated? The indexes `0,1,2 3,4,5 7` can be used as they are already been taken by X or O so should not be evaluated for their value ? This also means that indexes which are not available will not have their Q value updated, will this break the Q-learning procedure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are referring to as the situation where

> some indexes are not available

is simply the situation where some actions are not available/valid in some state. So, yes, the ${\arg \max }$ will be calculated based only on the available actions in that state. More formally, 
$$\underset{a \in \mathcal{A}(s)}{\arg \max } \, Q(s, a)$$

where $Q(s,a)$ has been initialized for all $s \in \mathcal{S}^{+}$ and $a \in \mathcal{A}(s)$ and $\mathcal{A}(s)$ is defined as the set of all actions available in state $s$.
See Sutton and Barto's [Intro to RL book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf), chapter 6 (the part on Q-learning).

In the same book (chapter 3), the authors state that:

> **To simplify notation**, we sometimes assume the special case in which
>   the action set is the same in all states and write it simply as $\mathcal{A}$.

Therefore, in many sources, you may see the $\arg \max$ expressed as $\underset{a \in \mathcal{A}} {\arg \max}$ or even $\underset{a} {\arg \max}$. It's implicit that it is taken with respect to the set of actions $\mathcal{A}(s)$ available in state $s$.